# Record last activity of a logged in user in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

In an application I am building in Pyramid,I have a users table with a field called 'last_activity'. This field is intented to store the timestamp of the last time a user visited a page in the system.

Since I'm still a bit new in pyramid, I don't know if pyramid has some sort of way to create a "common" view that can be  executed everytime a user visits any page in the site (in order to update the 'last_activity' field in this view function). Is this possible?

If that is not possible, what would you recommend me to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [events](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/events.html):

If you want to log the event at the beginning of the request:

```
@subscriber(NewRequest)
def mysubscriber(event):
    event.request.foo = 1
    # log an event based on the route and the user
```

I am fairly new to pyramid, so I don't know if this is the most "pyramidic" way to accomplish this.

It looks like that perhaps you could use some sort of callback too http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/hooks.html#using-response-callbacks

Comment: Oh, this saved my day! I used the add_finished_callback and that is exactly what I wanted. Also, good info about the events. Thanks so much @dm03514